# Access route data in global route listener

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to activate dark mode only on specific parts of my Angular application.

To achieve this, I flag corresponding routes like this :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'home',
  component: MyHomeComponent,
  data: {
    darkModeCompatible: true,
  },
},
```

and I implemented a global route listener like this :

```
this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
  .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((event) => {
    const router = this.router;
    // How to I access to the route data here ?

    // [...] add/remove custom class on the body element
  });
```

The question is : how do I access to the route data in this global route listener ?